# Show possible points in ZXing.Net barcode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, zxing

I'm integrating the ZXing.Net's barcode reader in an app I'm working and I would like to know if it's possible to have the same behavior that their app has when scanning bar codes? I mean, it shows some yellow spots where it thinks there is a bar code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The component does not contain such property. You could write your own custom overlay, but then again, there is no event to see if the scanning is actually occurring, wich makes it impossible to show an effect on scanning, so my answer would be no, it's not possible.

Comment: Wouldn't the use of a custom overlay dictate that it is possible, just that it's not part of any API or something.

At first glance it looks like they just analyse the stream and show spots where the pixels show large amounts of repetitive contrast above a certain level. The larger and more frequent the contrast the larger the spots.

Comment: But you still would need a way to analyse the stream, wich i did not find. The custom overlay does indeed indicate that Xzing gives you the freedom to make it look like your own, but without an event or something to indicate that it is scanning, i wouldn't see how you could time an animation on that. I'm not stating this as a fact, just an observation, i'd love to be proven wrong :)

Comment: Again, I haven't looked into it, but if you can at least access the stream that ZXing is also using (i.e. directly or indirectly see the same pixels as ZXing is seeing), then you could write your own analyser. Just analyzing local contrast ratios and repeated dark/light pixels should be possible to implement. 

I admit, a lot more work then if they provided an API. But still a lot less work than actually writing your own barcode scanning logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the original ZXing.Net assembly (not the ZXing.Net.Mobile component)
you can use the event `ResultPointFound` of the `BarcodeReader` class.
The event is fired every time if a point of a potential barcode is found.
In the event handler you can draw your yellow dots.